# gmrf model for images

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, markov, markov-models

Can anyone explain how the parameters of the GMRF model can be estimated for an image using MATLAB?

I have tried the toolboxes like UGM.(http://www.di.ens.fr/~mschmidt/Software/UGM/trainMRF.html)

Comment: This is the first thing i can find googling: http://code.google.com/p/smitoolbox/source/browse/pmodels/gauss/gmrf.m?r=17999685c18d5ee7ccf70b40f183a63004f5ac2c

Comment: ya. ive seen that but it doesnt help with what im asking.

Comment: In that case I would recommend you to explain a bit more in detail what you have tried and where you are stuck. At the moment your question is quite broad and hard to answer.